# Identifying IC marked 'HYEXC'

Tags: identification, surface-mount

It’s an TFT speedometer. The markings on the burnt chip is HYEXC.

What IC is this?

[image]

Comment: the chip is not necessarily the actual location of failure

Comment: That SS34 looks damaged as well.

Comment: If it's a buck/boost converter: Was the input power reversed?

Answer (score 2):

It's a [Silergy SY7200AABC](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810311211_Silergy-Corp-SY7200AABC_C107309.pdf) LED driver.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/LED-Drivers_Silergy-Corp-SY7200AABC_C107309.html))

Comment: Thank you for this!!! How did you figure this out? This is exciting

Comment: @AgostinoDavidScanu Silergy is a popular manufacturer for these kind of DC-DC converters. They also always use plain 5 or 6 character markings, so it was the first manufacturer I checked by google searching `Silergy "HYxyz"`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a switcher due to the fact that there is an inductor right next to it, see if it's a [XD9261A08CER-Q](https://www.datasheetarchive.com/datasheet?id=ec6cbaf7fcc4a140a4fc766115a1af30d6a666&type=M&term=XD9261A3EDERQ)